# How to install Wireshark on my Dell with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation, wireshark

Can anybody help me installing WireShark?

My Computer: Core i5 Intel Inspiron 15 5558 DELL 8GB RAM 1TB HDD. UBUNTU 14.04

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`wireshark`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&searchon=names&keywords=wireshark) is in the universe repository:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wireshark
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Pretty important, after installing Wireshark, run:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common
```

(see https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/16343/install-wireshark-on-ubuntu)